# Can you damage the file system by forcing a shutdown or cold rebooting during startup?

Tags: macos, windows

My idea is that during startup (macOS or Windows), you can't damage the file system if you interrupt it as the drive is not being written to, just reading from.  I've heard that's not the case, and that during startup the drive may be written to.  what can be written to a startup drive during boot?

Please clear up my mind. Thank you.

Comment: You can always damage the file system. The chances are just greater or smaller. And are you talking about a hard drive or sold state drive?

Comment: Well I was thinking mostly of SSDs but I also deal with hard drives all the time.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to damage the file system by forcing a shutdown (i.e. for example by cutting off power) during startup.

During startup the operating system can write to files such as for example log files, pid files, caches, or in very extreme cases also swap files for virtual memory. Therefore the file system on disk can be modified by the operating system during startup - and thus there is a risk that something goes wrong if this is interrupted forcibly midways.

Modern file systems (such as the ones normally used on macOS systems) try to avoid corruption by the way of a technique called journaling. Therefore you'll probably experience that nothing goes wrong if you try interrupting the boot to test this out - however there is a risk.

Comment: I would like to add:[return]
Typically on any system, one of the first task the system has to do is to check the correct state of the file system from which it will run everything. On Unixes, and MacOS X, this is done with `fsck /`. This command is reading and **writing** on the most important filesystem on the disk. Depending on when you hit the power off, there might be no damage at all and there might be an unbootable system.

Comment: Thanks a lot all of you, great answers and discussion, you really helped me.  Love you all.

Answer (score 0):

@jksoegaard's answer is correct, and you could prove it yourself on Windows by using Sysinternals ProcMon at http://live.sysinternals.com/procmon.exe and use the option for Boot Logging and then reboot. You'll see plenty of write activity happens.